# geom_bar() visualization not displaying the data correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a labor force survey data that shows monthly job contribution categorized by firm-size. I am trying to visualize the employment or job contribution by firm size and month, using geom-bar. The code works without any errors but I don't think the visualization is reflecting the actual data.
Here is a data example:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
  job_firmsize_perc = c(11.9, 61.2, 6.7, 3.4, 4.5, 7.1, 75.1, 1.6, 5.5, 4.7, 8.6, 2, 1, NA, NA),
  month_year = rep(c(2023.16666666667, 2023.25, NA), c(6L, 7L, 2L)) |>
    structure(class = "yearmon"),
  company_size = c(
    "1001 to 5000 Employees", "10000+ Employees", "5001 to 10000 Employees",
    "1 to 50 Employees", "501 to 1000 Employees", "51 to 200 Employees",
    "10000+ Employees", "501 to 1000 Employees", "5001 to 10000 Employees",
    "51 to 200 Employees", "1001 to 5000 Employees", "201 to 500 Employees",
    "1 to 50 Employees", NA, NA
  ),
)
```

Then the visualization code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = month_year, y = job_firmsize_perc, fill = company_size))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=job_firmsize_perc), position = position_stack(vjust =0.9))+
    stat_summary(fun=sum,geom="bar")  +
      ylab("Share of jobs posted by company size") +
    labs(fill='Firm size')+ 
        xlab("Period") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text( size=12), legend.text=element_text(size=10))
```

Looking at the output below, we may infer that in March 2023, firms with "1001 to 5000 Employees" or the green area are only responsible for a small share of jobs in a given month, and the graph suggest that firms with "51 to 200 Employees" have a higher job creation share.
However, if we look at the df, firms with "1001 to 5000 Employees" had a share of 11.9% of total jobs created compared to 7.1% for firms with "51 to 200 Employees" in the same month but looking at the graph, one may conclude the opposite.

[image]

The solution proposed below by Mr. Spring works well, so my code is now:

```
ggplot(jobsper_firm_size, aes(x = month_year, y = job_firmsize_perc, fill = company_size))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=job_firmsize_perc), position = position_stack(vjust = 0))+
  geom_col() +
#stat_summary(fun=sum, geom="bar", position = position_stack()) +
  ylab("Share of jobs posted by company size") +
    labs(fill='Firm size')+ 
        xlab("Period") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text( size=12), legend.text=element_text(size=10))
```

output:
[image]

Comment: `stat_summary(fun=sum, geom="bar", position = position_stack()) +` or `geom_col() +` seems to provide the expected result if you replace the `stat_summary` line with those.